# Installing libpcre 3.35.X on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, deb

I'd like to upgrade the version of cppcheck that is available on ubuntu from 1.68 to 1.70. However, after downloading the DEB archive, I cannot install it because of a dependency on libpcre3.

```
$ sudo gdebi cppcheck_1.70-2_i386.deb 
...
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libpcre3 (>= 1:8.35)
```

Installing libpcre 3.35.* yields the following:

```
$ sudo gdebi libpcre3_8.35-7.2_i386.deb 
...
Do you want to install the software package? [Y/N]:Y
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre3:i386.
(Reading database ... 212075 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpcre3_8.35-7.2_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libpcre3:amd64 (1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Unpacking libpcre3:i386 (2:8.35-7.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package libpcre3:i386 (--install):
 package libpcre3:i386 2:8.35-7.2 cannot be configured because libpcre3:amd64 is at a different version (1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1)
dpkg: error processing package libpcre3:amd64 (--install):
 package libpcre3:amd64 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1 cannot be configured because libpcre3:i386 is at a different version (2:8.35-7.2)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpcre3:i386
 libpcre3:amd64
```

I still have the old version of libpcre installed because it seems that everything links against it. If I was to remove it, it would break a great many things.

I've also tried recompiling cppcheck, but it obviously requires the latest version of libpcre.

So, the question is, is there any way for me to install this on 14.04?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`. And the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to install a 32-bit package on a 64-bit system, which is OK, but to install a 32-bit package, the 64-bit package of the same version must be installed as well. Therefore install the `.deb` files for both systems at the **same** time:

First repair your installation:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that:

```
sudo dpkg -i libpcre3_8.35-7.2_i386.deb libpcre3_8.35-7.2_amd64.deb
```