# libglib2.0-0:amd64 install / remove broke whole ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I have Ubuntu bullseye 11.
I tried to install pspp that needed a version of libglib.
Then I tried to update libglib manually to a newer version.
Then my system was broken like below.

libglib2.0-0:amd64 install / remove broke whole ubuntu

```
elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 package libglib2.0-0:i386 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1 cannot be configured because libglib2.0-0:amd64 is at a different version (2.68.4-1ubuntu1)
Setting up man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Updating database of manual pages ...
man-db.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:i386

elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo apt-get install -f 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 appmenu-gtk-module-common : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 gdm3 : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.35.0)
 gnome-characters : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.40.0-3)
 gnome-shell : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.53.0)
 libfm-qt8 : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 libglib2.0-0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.33-0ubuntu5 is installed
                Depends: libffi8 (>= 3.4) but it is not installable
                Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.68.4-1ubuntu1) but 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1 is installed
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1) but 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1) but 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1)
 libglib2.0-dev-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1) but 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-tests : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1) but 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libqt5xdg3 : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 lightdm : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 packagekit : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 tracker : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 ubuntu-settings : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.53.4-3ubuntu1~)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo dpkg --force-all --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 package libglib2.0-0:i386 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1 cannot be configured because libglib2.0-0:amd64 is at a different version (2.68.4-1ubuntu1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:i386

elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo apt-get install -f libglib2.0-0=2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 appmenu-gtk-module-common : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 gdm3 : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.35.0)
 gnome-characters : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.40.0-3)
 gnome-shell : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.53.0)
 libfm-qt8 : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1)
 libqt5xdg3 : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 lightdm : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 packagekit : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 tracker : Depends: libglib2.0-bin
 ubuntu-settings : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.53.4-3ubuntu1~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: That my system is broken, and how i can fix this.

Comment: Since you have failed to give even the most basic info such as version of Ubuntu that is next to impossible. How do we even know what commands you ran to cause this output. Please edit the question and add some details not just this log.

Comment: What is "Ubuntu Bullseye 11"? There is Ubuntu, which typically has versions like "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" or "Ubuntu 21.10", and there is Debian, and the latest stable release of that is "Debian 11 Bullseye". Which OS and version do you have?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Debian 11/Bullseye is not Ubuntu*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing libpcre 3.35.X on ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685023/installing-libpcre-3-35-x-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

classic solution did not work

Output said to downgrade but apt-get could not resolve downgrade process:

```
sudo apt-get install -f libglib2.0-0=2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1
```

Then i run `sudo aptitude`, choosing some options there
(clicking on the related library) and some more clicks that do not remember.

and voila!!!
it downgraded many libraries including libglib2.0.

No broken system anymore!

Note that the below command proposed to uninstall almost entire system!:

```
   sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends  libglib2.0-0
```